# sending push notification using FCM on android device

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can able to send the push notification on my android application using the console. but using server side code, I get the successfully message send notification but actually notification does not able to receive at device end. Please, tell me what is wrong with my code:

```
public static string SendPushNotification() {
        try {
            string applicationID = "AAAA4GkXVHA:....-qRw";

            string senderId = "963..28";

            string deviceId = "APA91bHLV...IC4s";

            WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            var data = new {
                to = deviceId,
                notification = new {
                    body = "hema",
                    title = "hem",
                    //priority = "normal",
                    //sound = "Enabled"
                },
            };

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream()) {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse()) {
                    using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream()) {
                        using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse)) {
                            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                            string str = sResponseFromServer;
                            return str;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            string str = ex.Message;
            return str;
        }
    }
```

where I got the response in return is as follows :
 {"multicast_id":8288766196764532656,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1481612825945796%6ad79a87f9fd7ecd"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Sending the json in right format:

```
{
  "to" : "APA91bHLV__P6Qer8U70j82blZt0VdDgc2zo_4DtAD4_MtE-......",
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "Success!",
    "title" : "Hema",
    "icon" : "myicon"
  }
}
```

To check it properly, you can also use the postman:
[image: Postman testing FCM server to device(ios or android)]

Answer (score 0):

Even I experienced the same problem. Finish all the steps in connecting the FCM from Client side. If you implement GetMessage() method from client side, only then your device is able to get the Notification from Server side

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small tutorial for this: https://www.kendar.org/?p=/tutorials/notifications with an Android app and a .Net core Server. To summarize here is the "main" server code

```
    public NotificationResult Send(NotificationModel messageData)
    {
        var result = "-1";
        var webAddr = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "key=PROJECTSETTINGS->Cloud Messagings->Server Key");
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string strNJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new NotificationMessage
            {
                To = "/topics/ServiceNow",
                Data = new NotificationData
                {
                    Description = messageData.Description,
                    IncidentNo = messageData.IncidentNo,
                    ShortDesc = messageData.ShortDesc
                },
                Notification = new Notification
                {
                    Title = "ServiceNow: Incident No." + messageData.IncidentNo,
                    Text = "Notification"
                }
            });
            streamWriter.Write(strNJson);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return new NotificationResult
        {
            Result = result
        };
    }
```

And the classes that wrap the message to FCM (with the Json annotations to correct the mismatch between .Net and Json naming standards)

```
    public class NotificationData
{
    public string ShortDesc { get; set; }
    public long IncidentNo { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class Notification
{
    public Notification()
    {
        Sound = "default";
    }
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("sound")]
    public string Sound { get; set; }
}
public class NotificationMessage
{
    [JsonProperty("to")]
    public string To { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public NotificationData Data { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("notification")]
    public Notification Notification { get; set; }

}
```